# How to configure Extjs 4.1.x MVC Application in Single JS File

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.1

`Extjs 4.1.x` used by me. I would like to merge entire `MVC application` in a single js file. For these reason all the `requires` fields was removed by me as usual as  I removed `views`, `controllers`, `stores`, `models` fields/properties from `Application`, `Controllers`. In this case views are rendered well without `store`. But when I used `store` it's unable to resolve `store`. that's why unable to run application. Any example of `Extjs 4.1.x MVC` application integrated in a single `js` file. because I want to skip dependency loading dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try sencha cmd tool.

http://www.sencha.com/products/sencha-cmd/download

Comment: Sencha CMD and SDK already used by me, But my goal was different that was dynamically build Extjs MVC files into a single Java Script file in Server Side. Sencha CMD and SDK good for those who are interested to build static Java Script library. finally I able to compile, obfuscate but unable to get flavor like Sencha CMD build. Although all required libraries merged into single file Extjs trying to load required js files again. This made me annoying.

Answer (score 1):

You should not remove `requires` or `uses` properties!! These are used by the commandtool to detect which class will be needed and at which time. Where

```
requires
```

is the strict one that forces the loader (and buildtool) to load the class strictly before the requiring class, while the

```
uses
```

property is sort of loose and only make sure that the class is ready at the time the `onReady` block get's executed.

What you don't need strictly to required are classes that you extend cause the builder/loader set them automatically to required.

Answer (score 0):

My answer to the similar question "How to package (minify) an extjs 4 application" : https://stackoverflow.com/a/24331758/1983903

For about two years I have not found the appropriate tool to make ExtJS applications builds easy. Then I decided to write light-weight build tool for ExtJS applications on my own. Here it is:

Extapp : https://github.com/liberborn/extapp

It is some kind of alternative to JS Compiler module in the Sencha.cmd. You don't need to install the huge Sencha.cmd software on deployment servers to do the simple build job. Just run one jar file in the command line and you will get compiled app.